# Saving the result of a loop function

Tags: python, for-loop

I've recently started to learn Python and I'm just getting used to it. I'm currently doing a simple probability experiment to just play around with the functions.

I've written the following

```
import numpy as np
def pr_n_row(manager):
    pr=(1-(0.5**10))**manager
    print(pr)
    return
for manager in range(1,3001):
    pr=(1-(0.5**10))**manager
    print(pr)
```

So, what I'm trying to do now is save the results here and plot it on a graph where on the horizontal axis I have the numbers from 1 to 3000 and on the vertical axis I have the result from my *for loop* which also has 3000 results.

I would appreciate any help here and also any tips on if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: create a list outside of the for loop and store the result in a list inside the for loop using list.append()

Answer (score 0):

```
out_list=[]
for manager in range(1,3001):
    pr=(1-(0.5**10))**manager
    print(pr)
    out_list.append(pr)

print(out_list)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [Reminder: How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the results temporarily, then define a list outside the 'for' loop and use the `.append()` function to write your results to the list

```
    import numpy as np
    def pr_n_row(manager):
        pr=(1-(0.5**10))**manager
        print(pr)
        return
    list = []
    for manager in range(1,3001):
        pr=(1-(0.5**10))**manager
        list.append(pr)
        print(pr)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. You mentioned temporarily. Can you please tell me what permanent would be? Best, Dan

Comment: the best answer would be saving the results to a .CSV file, here’s a tutorial explaining it: https://realpython.com/python-csv/